# Youtube logo hide parameter not working in HTML 5 player for iPad and iphone

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video

As i saw on this page http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-youtube-videos-logoless/19532/ about how to hide youtube logo from player for any video

I tried here for example http://jsbin.com/ikulax with this code

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HSQzUixVCzo?modestbranding=1" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Logo is still showing on iPad and iphone but not on other flash enabled browser.

Is there any other method to hide the logo from HTML 5 player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a answer in email from a Youtube Intern. That Currently it's not possible to hide youtube logo from HTML 5 player.